# Using Jacobian to find tangent plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, jacobian

I'm really stuck on this task. I need to find the tangent plane and the normal vector for this set of functions :

x=a cos$\phi$ cos$\psi$,

y=b sin$\phi$ cos$\psi$,

z=c*sin$\psi$

I know the general formula for finding the tangent plane:
$z-z_0=z_x'(x-x_0)+z_y'(y-y_0)$ if z=f(x,y) for one function. However, I don't understand the notion of a tangent plane for a set of functions with many variables, similarly presented in the example above.
Also, I saw that somehow I can find the Jacobian and hence the partial derivatives of $\phi$ and $\psi$, but still I don't understand how to apply it to the tangent plane formula.

Comment: With this you parametrize the surface of an ellipsoid. You get $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$.  Then this an example of a surface $V(x, y, z)=0$. The gradient of V at a point on this surface will be normal to the surface at every such point. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Well, suppose i've found connection between ellipsoid equation and my current task. However, what do i do in general case?